# Keep track of mouse coordinates on jsplumb canvas

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, jsplumb

So I've been trying to implement a "paste" function for objects in a jsplumb canvas, but I can't figure out how to find the x and y position within the canvas of the mouse. I've tried using an ng-mouseover property to keep track of it, but it only returns the proper event when I move outside/inside the canvas, and when I move into and out of objects. Here's an excerpt:

```
<js-plumb-canvas ng-click="setActiveStateFromEvent($event)" ondragover="event.preventDefault()" ng-mousemove="updatePos(e)" ondrop="event.preventDefault(); $(this).scope().drop(event)" on-connection="onConnection"
                                   x="canvas.x" y="canvas.y" zoom="canvas.zoomlevel"
                                 ng-style="{left: '-1000px', top: '-1000px'}">
                        <div ng-if="!refreshing" ng-include="'partials/defaultState.html'"></div>
                    </js-plumb-canvas>
```

And here's the function:

```
$scope.updatePos = function(e) {
        console.log(e);
    };
```